# Is there a way to use find and aggregate together in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I m a MongoDB begginer and I have the following problem:

I have a document format(sorry for lack of definition) as follows in MongoDB:

[image: document_format]

And I want to query the top 10 albums of the worst genre of a decade I choose.

Firstly I did an aggregate that gave me in the last stage the worst genre of the decade I choose to use as comparison later (BDA1 being my database and album my collection I want to aggregate and find on):

```
BDA1.album.aggregation(
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      release_date: {
        $toDate: "$release_date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      sales_amount: {
        $convert: {
          input: "$sales_amount",
          to: "int"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "release_date": {
        $gte: new ISODate("2009-01-01"),
        $lt: new ISODate("2021-01-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$band.band_genre",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$band.band_genre",
      total: {
        $sum: "$sales_amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

(Sorry for the lack of good formatting but I took the code from a pipeline I used to do the aggregation in MongoDB Compass.)

That resulted in:

[image: Final result of aggregation query]

But my question now is: how do I do to use that aggregate result in what I can only assume is a find command where band.band_genre equals to the genre I just calculated in the aggregation?

I have been searching SO for a while with no results and google as well.

Any suggestions?

(Anything that I have forgot to mention that u feel is important to understand the problem please say and I will edit it in)

Comment: You can use `$match` stage , no!!

Comment: Can u use match for an update as well? @varman

Comment: What you expect with this aggregation? Sometimes i misunderstood or question not clear

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want this aggregation to get the worst genre of a specific decade, set by me and I want the genre that the aggregation uses to find the albuns that are associated with that album in that timeframe. And the idea is to update the sales amount of that album so that genre stops being the worst genre